# SFDX Deploy to MDO overwrite package Settings for Post Install

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

When using SFDX to Deploy metadata to a packaging org, the package settings get overwritten.

i.e.

**Convert Source**

sfdx force:source:convert -d .... -n "Package Name"

**Deploy**

sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d .... -u .....

In the packaging org the package has a **Post Install** value defined.

After the deploy however, the Post Install value is reset to null.

**Q:** Is there any way to not have the deploy overwrite the Post Install Package Setting?